# converting svn repo to git using reposurgeon

Tags: git, svn, svnadmin

I am trying to convert an svn repo to git using [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon).

Here is what I did ( have a repo.map file that has the svn name -> git name mapping):

```
svnadmin dump /home/subversion > repo.svn
reposurgeon "verbose 1" "repo.svn" "authors read" "write repo.fi"
```

reposurgeon runs for many hours (lots of swapping as it is a 12GB dump file), and everything looks good. Here is the output I get:

```
    reposurgeon: verbose 1
    reposurgeon: from repo.svn...copynodes+filemaps+copysets+commits+branches+parents+root+branchlinks+svn-mergeinfo+tagifying+tagify-empty+polishing+canonicalizing+resets+debubbling+renumbering+14163 revisions (1/s)...(9810.18 sec) done.
reposurgeon: r13: deleting parentless zero-op commit.
.
.
.
reposurgeon: r13726: deleting parentless zero-op commit.
    2012-12-24T01:16:23Z * repo.svn
```

At this point reposurgeon just sits. I'm not sure where to look for a solution at this point, as it never actually gives me an error message. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: You should try asking somewhere ESR hangs out, like IRC.  That looks like a lot of commits, he recently introduced some performance optimizations that may interest you.

Comment: @DanielJacobs: have you tried running the job interactively? I have noticed subtle discrepancies between running stuff on the command line and from a script. I also use the interactive prompt to develop my lift script.

Answer (score 6):

It's successfully imported the repository, but then it goes to process the `authors read` command, but you didn't specify a file. At this point it's actually waiting for the file to appear on stdin. Use `authors read <author-map` where author-map is the name of the file containing the map.

You'll also want to change the write command to `write >repo.fi`, for similar reasons.

Comment: How do I get such an author-map?

Comment: the author-map is just a text file that you create containing lines that look like "ferd = Ferd J. Foonly <foonly@foo.com> -0500".