# How do I convert an svn repo to git using reposurgeon?

Tags: git, svn, converters, reposurgeon

Can you give an example, how I add the path to my old svn and create a git folder from it, that contains the whole history and all branches/tags?

I found [this site](http://www.goebel-consult.de/blog/convert-svn-repo-directly-to-git-or-hg-no-dump-files-needes) is this worth a try? It uses `svnpull`, which is not on my system can I use `repopuller` instead?

I installed reposurgeon with

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends xmlto asciidoc unp
wget http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/reposurgeon-3.7.tar.gz
unp reposurgeon-3.7.tar.gz
cd reposurgeon-3.7
make
make install
```

(I would install without the recommendations, cause that would be about 700MB not needed here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting svn repo to git using reposurgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017127/converting-svn-repo-to-git-using-reposurgeon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the site is a bit outdated.

svnpull is replaced by repopuller by now. And you don't need that either if you are on the same server.

I adapted the script:

```
nano /usr/local/sbin/reposurgeon-convert-svn2git
```

and entered:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT=myproject
svnrepo=svn+ssh://rubo77@myserver.de/var/svn-repos/$PROJECT
# or something like svnrepo=https://svn.origo.ethz.ch/$PROJECT

gitrepo=/tmp/$PROJECT-git

cd /tmp

# start over with:
#rm $PROJECT-mirror/ $PROJECT-git/ -Rf

echo 
echo pull/copy the repository...
#repopuller $svnrepo
# or copy it if it is on the same server:
cp -av /var/svn-repos/$PROJECT /tmp/$PROJECT-mirror
echo 
echo start conversion...

reposurgeon <<EOF
read /tmp/$PROJECT-mirror
prefer git
edit
references lift
rebuild $gitrepo
EOF
echo ...finished 

# now filter out all falsly generated .gitignore files:
cd $gitrepo/
git filter-branch --force --index-filter      \
 "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(find . -name .gitignore|xargs )"  \
 --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I filter out the .gitignore files like [github has documented](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) with **filter-branch** because otherwise, they will create commits in all tags (see note below). You have to create a new .gitignore file when you are done.

This may take a while, so you should start it inside `tmux` or `screen` with

```
tmux
bash /usr/local/sbin/reposurgeon-convert-svn2git
```

---

Take care, that all your tags are git conform.

I got the error

```
reposurgeon% reposurgeon: exporting...fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: refs/tags/version 3.6.2
```

So I cleaned up the svn repository and removed this branch, so all tags and branches are conform:

```
svn rm "$svnrepo/tags/version 3.6.2"
```

and deleted it from all history with this script:
[How do I remove an SVN tag completely that contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705942/how-do-i-remove-an-svn-tag-completely-that-contains-spaces?lq=1)

Then I started over with the script:

```
rm $PROJECT-mirror/ $PROJECT-git/ -Rf
bash /usr/local/sbin/reposurgeon-convert-svn2git
```

---

**Note:**
Without removing the `.gitignore` files, it looks all the same in git as in SVN before **except one thing**: all **tags** are ordered in the log at the exact date they were tagged, instead of the commit they started ad. It seems a `.gitignore` file is added there in the conversion process to each branch and tag, but that .gitignore-file results in a commit inside those tags with the timestamp of the tag-creation.
New tags are ok, they appear right at the revision they belong to. (see [Convert an SVN repository to git with reposurgeon without creating .gitignore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822020))

Comment: I used the blender and nut conversions as samples how to wield the tool. But yeah, the documentation leaves a bit to wish for. It's better to read the code.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: So did you manage to convert it with the tags-branches at the right place (date)?

Comment: so far, yes. But I am using the version from `master` in the Git repo. Well possible there are differences. To mutate a tag name you can use the `filter` action. It worked for me, although I still have to get `path` to work as advertised :)