# How can I convert an SVN repository to GIT without annotated tags?

Tags: git, svn, reposurgeon

I used reposurgeon to convert ma svn into a git repository here: ([How do I convert an svn repo to git using reposurgeon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700593/how-do-i-convert-an-svn-repo-to-git-using-reposurgeon)).

It seems like it converted all tags to "annotated tags". How can I change that beaviour?

I tried `tagify` option but that didn't change it.

The problem is, that the converted tags are shown in the log at the place when I created the tag and not at the place of the revision they belong to. In SVN they are shown at the right place in the log where they belong, no matter how long later I created them.

It seems like this has to do something with that reposurgeon adds a commit for .gitignore in each tag that looks like this:

```
# A simulation of Subversion default ignores, generated by reposurgeon.
*.o
*.lo
...
*.pyo
*.rej
*~
.#*
.*.swp
.DS_store
# The contents of the svn:ignoreproperty on the branch root.
*~
nbproject
*.project
```

How can I make reposurgeon not create such a commit for gitignore in all tags? And let it create simple tags that don't appear in the timeline as a commit?

Comment: What do you want them to be?  A different type of tag?  Not tagged at all?  "Annotated tags" are similar to SVN tags so this is a reasonable default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotated tags seem to be correct.

The problem lies somewhere else:

[Convert an SVN repository to git with reposurgeon without creating .gitignore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822020)