# Convert an SVN repository to git with reposurgeon without creating .gitignore files?

Tags: git, svn, reposurgeon

I used reposurgeon to convert my svn into a git repository here: ([How do I convert an svn repo to git using reposurgeon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700593/how-do-i-convert-an-svn-repo-to-git-using-reposurgeon)).

The problem is, that the converted tags are shown in the log at the place when I created the tag and not at the place of the revision they belong to. In SVN they are shown at the right place in the log where they belong, no matter how long later I created them.

It seems like this has to do something with that reposurgeon adds a commit for .gitignore in each tag that looks like this:

```
# A simulation of Subversion default ignores, generated by reposurgeon.
*.o
*.lo
...
*.pyo
*.rej
*~
.#*
.*.swp
.DS_store
# The contents of the svn:ignoreproperty on the branch root.
*~
nbproject
*.project
```

How can I make reposurgeon not create such a commit for gitignore in all tags? And let it create simple tags that don't appear in the timeline as a commit?

The [reposurgeon manual sais:](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/reposurgeon.html)

> **user-generated .gitignore**
>
> This message means means reposurgeon has found a .gitignore file in the Subversion repository it is analyzing. This probably happened
>   because somebody was using git-svn as a live gateway, and created
>   ignores which may or may not be congruent with those in the generated
>   .gitignore files that the Subversion ignore properties will be
>   translated into. You'll need to make a policy decision about which set
>   of ignores to use in the conversion, and possibly to delete either the
>   generated .gitignore files or the user-created ones.

But no example how to make that decision. How can I manage this?

Comment: You might have to do some additional 'surgery' using `git-filter-branch` to make the converted repository look how you want.  It is possible to do things like strip a file completely from history, or edit files in history, or move tags, etc., but hard to post a generic answer to that

Comment: The main problem seems to be, that the SVN was already used with git over SVN which created the `.gitignore` files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You'll need to make a policy decision about which set of ignores to
>   use in the conversion, and possibly to delete either the generated
>   .gitignore files or the user-created ones.

Do you have a .gitignore from before the conversion?  If so compare it to the one from after.  It seems like this policy decision is separate from your "sequence of commits" question, right?  Basically, the policy question is just "get a final .gitignore you like".  Do what it takes to get there.

In git, the .gitignore file is managed exactly like any other file.  So you can say `git log .gitignore` and see what commits contribute to it.  Say that the entire .gitignore file was commited in one block 10 commits ago and you want it parted out.  If so, you can do a `git rebase --interactive HEAD~11` and **edit** the commit in question.  Do `git add --partial .gitignore; git commit` for each line you want broken out.  Then `git rebase --continue` to conclude.

If you want the newly itemized commits to each be part of a larger code commit that they correspond to, then you would rebase -i again to shift the order around and **squash** them with their partner commit.  If this sounds like unnecessary work, it probably is.  If you can, I would recommend you focus on the integrity of the end state of the repo and less about a perfect expression of history.

Note: I don't understand your use of the term "tag" in this context, since both SVN and git have "tags", but you seem not to be referring to either.  Perhaps "ignore line" or "entry" would be clearer.

To purge history in version control is problematic.  Changing history on all branches is effectively creating a new repository, since there is no longer continuity to downstream followers for *anything* (everybody must rebase).  But if you want to do it, for each branch, find all the .gitignores in the filesystem and see what commits touched them:

```
  git log `find . -name .gitignore`
```

Then you can do the **rebase --interactive** steps described above to alter those commits.  If the commit affects *only* the .gitignore, you can delete it.  But obviously if the commit touches 100 files including the .gitignore, you have to separate out the good from the bad.

Alternatively, if you know the paths of all the .gitignore files (checkout each branch and run the **find** from above), then you can do something like [github has documented](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) with **filter-branch**:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter      \
 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .gitignore path/to/other/.gitignore'  \
 --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

They also mention a BFG java tool, but filter-branch should do what you need.

Comment: I don't want any.gitignore files at all. svn doesn't have them and they only mess things up here. I will create one (and only one!) when I am finished converting.

Comment: With tags I mean version tags. They are a standard. There are branches and tags. Tags usually don't contain commits. But after my conversion they all contain one empty commit with this gitignore file

Comment: Could you add an example how I can remove all .gitignore files from all branches and tags in the whole history?

Comment: Added.  The last example is probably what you want.

Comment: You can use `find` to find all instances of `.gitignore` in the repo and pass this to your command: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(find . -name .gitignore|xargs )" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
`

Comment: You should move the "Alternative" to the top of your answer, cause that is how it works with an acceptable amount of work. Your other tips are good, but produce far too much work with hundredths of tags and branches

Answer (score 2):

After reading in your subversionrepository, just add:

```
expunge /gitignore/
```

That will remove all the .gitignore files that reposurgeon automatically added.

Comment: Will it just remove them with another commit? or will it delete them from history and also delete the commits that added them?

Comment: They're added as part of existing commits, IIRC. This purges those files from the history completely (as if they had never existed).

Comment: If they are indeed their own commits, you can figure out the commit message marker, and then `/whatever-marker/ squash --pushback` will delete the commit.

Comment: expunge seems to delete all .gitignores, that is great!. But now there are hundredths of emptycommits in between: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXEQ.png Can I get rid of those too?

Comment: Are they actually empty commits, or just tags with the name "emptycommit"?

Comment: I don't know. But the screenshot shows them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXEQ.png How could I find out more details on them? I always use smartGit/hg

Comment: @rubo77: no it will remove them without another commit. That is: it will appear as if the files never existed. But beware of inconsistencies you can introduce this way.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: yes, but did you see the remaining problem?

Comment: @rubo77: obviously with `/^emptycommit-/n delete` ;) (`n` is to look for "names", like tags - and those are actually by default tags after `expunge`)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used reposurgeon, but I've converted many svn repositories to git using the built-in `git svn ...` commands.  I've followed the directons on http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial and http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git.

Answer (score 0):

@robrich

Author of reposurgeon here.  Do not use git-svn for conversions!  It's a disaster area. See this PSA:

http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=6778