# SVN - Merge history while recreating repository structure

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn

in preparation to change the VCS from SVN to Git on legacy projects, I stumbled about the necessity to arrange the projects in a certain way to make proper use of `svn2git` , that is

1. Project_1

- trunk/

  - lib.../
- tags/
- branches/

2. Project_2
   ...

I know that directories, including their history can be moved to new folders using `svn mv --parents SRC DST`.  Yet I face the particular challenge of such structure:

1. trunk

- Project_1

  - lib.../
- Project_2

  - lib.../

2. branches

- branch_1

  - Projekt_1.../
  - Projekt_2.../
- branch_2

3. tags

Is there a way to merge the history of  `trunk/Project_1`, `branches/branch_1/Project_1` etc into one new folder `Project_1` with corresponding subdirectories as svn2git expect ?

My current solution is:

```
svn mv --parents trunk/Project_1 ./Project_1/trunk
svn mv --parents branches/branch_1/Project_1 ./Project_1/branches/branch_1
```

, but obviously the history of the new dir "Project_1" is empty

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `svn2git`, because

- even mentioned `git-svn` allow more flexibility in initial SVN-tree
- *if* core `git-svn` will not be able to handle your tree correctly (but I don't think so) your can use SubGit, which cover (with [properly configured options](https://subgit.com/documentation/import-book.html)) even **extremely exotic** cases

Answer (score 0):

> with corresponding subdirectories as svn2git expect

I don't know about [`svn2git`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843107/how-to-use-svn2git-on-repository) (never used it even once), but **[`git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)** itself is very flexible and accepts many sorts of weird nonstandard svn directory structures.

With `git-svn`, you don't have to `svn mv` anything. You just have to call `git svn init` with properly configured options:

> ```
> -T<trunk_subdir>
> --trunk=<trunk_subdir>
> -t<tags_subdir>
> --tags=<tags_subdir>
> -b<branches_subdir>
> --branches=<branches_subdir>
> -s
> --stdlayout
> ```

After `git svn init` and before `git svn fetch`, you may review and fixup the trunk/branches/tags matching patterns in `.git/config`. There, you can remap svn paths using glob patterns, and you can also ignore svn paths by glob patterns.

So if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you'll have 2 git repos, `Project_1` and `Project_2`. To obtain `Project_1`, you'd do steps roughly along the lines:

```
SVNBASEURL=svn+ssh://user@subversion-server.example/top

mkdir Project_1; cd Project_1
git init
git svn init \
  --trunk=trunk/Project_1 \
  --branches='branches/*/Project_1' \
  --tags='tags/*/Project_1' \
  "$SVNBASEURL"/

# review/edit/fix/tune .git/config into shape

git svn fetch
```

And similarly for `Project_2`. Good luck!